# Azure Table Storage: Is there a way to check if the property does exist?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am new to Azure and doing some migration task. The thing I came up with is a need to check whether a property already exists in all entities, and if not, I would use `InsertOrMergeEntityAsync` method.

The question is, how to do this check if the property already exists or not? As usually an entity represents some entity in the code which has some pre-defined properties. But in my case case I need to check whether the property does exist or not in the existing data on Storage account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I can think of is to check each entity if has the property.

Sample code like below:

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("xx", "xxx"), true);
        CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference("table_name");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();

        TableOperation op1 = TableOperation.Retrieve<DynamicTableEntity>("partitionKey", "rowkey");
        TableResult result = table.Execute(op1);
        if (result.Result != null)
        {               
            if (((DynamicTableEntity)result.Result).Properties.ContainsKey("Emails"))
            {
                //the table contains the property(column) Emails, then you can do something.
            }
            else
            {
                //Does not contain the property(column) Emails, do something
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate more on Ivan's answer.

Essentially `Azure Tables` are `Schema Less Key/Value Pair Store` thus unlike a relational database table, there's no pre-defined schema of a table. You can put anything inside a table.

As to how to check whether or not an attribute exists, Ivan's answer is correct. You will have to fetch all entities and check for the presence of a particular attribute in each entity.